# I really don't seem to get the wait SKAction for a range

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, skaction

Sorry if this sounds too primitive. I really don't seem to get how the wait SKAction works for a range. I've seen a few posts, but I they don't clearly explain (to my understanding) how to calculate my range. For example I saw the ranges below:

```
SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.5, withRange: 3.0),  //Wait between 1.0 and 4.0 seconds
SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.65, withRange: 0.7),//Wait between 0.3 and 1.0 seconds
```

I am not sure how to reconcile the above to calculate a waiting times of between 1.0 to 2.0 seconds and 0.2 to 0.8 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `forDuration` time is the **average** time of the action. the `withRange` times gives a tolerance on either side of the `forDuration` time.

Divide the `withRange` time by 2 and add/subtract it from the `forDuration` time.

```
SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.5, withRange: 3.0),  //Wait between 1.0 and 4.0 seconds
//3.0 / 2 = 1.5; 2.5 - 1.5 = 1.0; 2.5 + 1.5 = 4.0

SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.65, withRange: 0.7),//Wait between 0.3 and 1.0 seconds
//0.7 / 2 = 0.35; 0.65 - 0.35 = 0.3; 0.65 + .035 = 1.0
```

So if you want wait times between 1.0 and 2.0 seconds use

```
SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.5, withRange: 1.0)
```

and for times between 0.2 and 0.8 seconds, use

```
SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5, withRange: 0.6)
```

A general formula for calculating forDuration and withRange values is this:

```
forDuration = t_min + (t_max - t_min) / 2
withRange = (t_max - t_min)
```

Comment: Cool stoy, Hansel.

Comment: @Fluidity Thanks, Olaf!